# How to Write Unit Tests for Functions That Contain SAPUI5 Core API?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sapui5, sinon, qunit

I'm new to qUnit with UI5.

I want to test one function `formatter.js`

```
formatDate: function(sTimeStamp) {
  if (sTimeStamp) {
    var iTimeStamp = Number(sTimeStamp.match(/\d/g).join("")), 
        oDateTimeFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(); 
    return oDateTimeFormat.format(new Date(iTimeStamp));
  }
  return sTimeStamp;
},
```

Unit test for it:

```
function formatDateTestCase(assert, sValue, fExpectedNumber) {
  var fDate = formatter.formatDate(sValue);
  assert.strictEqual(fDate, fExpectedNumber, "Format Date was correct");
}

QUnit.test("Should return valid date", function (assert) {
  formatDateTestCase.call(this, assert, "/Date(1510026665790)/", "Nov 7, 2017, 11:51:05 AM");
});
```

Obviously, this test case will fail when I change language setting. How to improve it?

---

I think the main problem here is that `formatDate` is a function with side effects. Should I improve this function itself? By adding locale in `formatDate`?

Or should I use `DateFormat` in my test case? Which will make my test meaningless.

Comment: Why would you write a test case for a UI5 core functionality? Your test will only prove that the code by SAP works correctly (and that you understood their API).

Comment: @Marc, 1. for test coverage. 2. I just gave a simple example here, there might be other complex logic which contains `DateFormat`, how to stub it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should mock the calls to `DateFormat` here to be able to independently test your code.

**Unit Test Considerations**

Strictly speaking the point of a Unit Test is to test your - and only your - Unit. You should not test any dependent API. One could argue about that in general but I would definitely NOT recommend to test SAPUI5 API.

One the other hand I would strongly recommend to test the `if` statement and the Regex part with invalid params (e.g. `undefined`) and invalid strings. This will ensure your formatter to always work and to return sth. meaningful if it is an empty string.

**Sinon.JS: Mocks, Stubs and Spys**

You should stub `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()` in your specific test so that the method returns a predictable value (e.g. think of I18N in `DateFormat` that would give you different test results in different languages).

To do that SAPUI5 already ships with [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/) (be aware of the version included: SAPUI5 1.44 -> Sinon.JS 1.14). Here is a basic example:

```
sap.ui.define([
  "my/module/formatter",
  "sap/ui/core/format/DateFormat",
  "sap/ui/thirdparty/sinon",
  "sap/ui/thirdparty/sinon-qunit"
], function (formatter, DateFormat) {

  QUnit.test("Should return valid date", function (assert) {
    // stub the method
    sinon.stub(DateFormat, "getDateTimeInstance");
    // ensure a predictable outcome
    DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance.returns({
      format: function(oDate) {
        return oDate.getTime();
      }
    });

    var fDate = formatter.formatDate("/Date(1510026665790)/");
    assert.strictEqual(fDate, "1510026665790", "Format Date was correct");
    // Optional: test if the stubbed function was called
    assert.ok(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance.calledOnce);

    // don't forget to restore the stub so that it does not interfere with other tests
    DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance.restore();
  });

});
```

By stubbing `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance` you stop testing core API and it's outcomes and you can focus on what matters most: YOUR code.

BR Chris

Comment: Should I stub `oDataModel.read/create/createEntry/update/remove` ?

Comment: You should not rely on a backend or a specific backend response in your unit tests. You could also go with mock server and fix mock data. In general it's probably easier to just mock those things than simulating it. Depends a little bit on your approach to unit tests, too (pure unit tests vs. integration testing with unit testing instruments).